# How would I re-write this to be a 3-level JSON with YEAR being 3rd search criteria (make/model/year) that leads to example URL?

Tags: json

Looking to make YEAR the third search criteria that then leads to the example URL. I believe that there are 2 kinds of syntax to do this but if you could use this syntax I would appreciate it, and if you need to use another please explain why. Here is the plnkr I am trying to modify. http://plnkr.co/edit/RnCdfnrX0jy3RvmXjF56 Thank you.

```
"bmw":[
    ["1","series 1","http://www.example.com/bmw-1-series.htm"],
    ["2","series 3","http://www.example.com/bmw-2-series.htm"],
    ["3","series 5"],
    ["4","series 7"]
],
"mercedes":[
    ["6","class A"],
    ["7","class B"],
    ["8","class C"],
    ["9","class E"]
],
"audi":[
    ["10","a3"],
    ["11","a4"],
    ["12","a5"],
    ["13","a6"]
],
"volkswagen":[
    ["14","polo"],
    ["15","golf"],
    ["16","cady"]
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "search criteria"? And hierarchical URL schemes have nothing to do with JSON...

Comment: I'm trying to emulate the "Select Your Vehicle" feature on this site <a>http://causa.com/customfit/</a> and I'm not a programmer, so feel free to tell me how to reword this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this updated plunker or snippet: http://plnkr.co/edit/4zJoRr26CSSjPa3T74rs?p=preview

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tabMarque = [];

  $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/e9xkz', function(data) {

    // alert(data);

    $.each(data, function(index, val) {
      tabMarque[index] = val;
    });
  });

  $('#Serie').change(function(event) {
    // alert('Marque_change');
    var marque = $('#Marque').val();
    // alert(marque);

    var htmlOption = '<option value="0">Choix du an</option>';
    if (marque !== '0') {
      var itemsMarque = tabMarque[marque];
      //alert(JSON.stringify(itemsMarque));
      $.each(itemsMarque, function(key, value) {
        //alert("k=" + key + " v=" + JSON.stringify(value));
        htmlOption += '<option value="' + value[0] + '">' + value[2] + '</option>';
      });
    }
    $('#Year').empty();
    $('#Year').html(htmlOption);
  });

  $('#Marque').change(function(event) {
    // alert('Marque_change');
    var marque = $(this).val();
    // alert(marque);

    var htmlOption = '<option value="0">Choix du serie</option>';
    if (marque !== '0') {
      var itemsMarque = tabMarque[marque];
      //alert(JSON.stringify(itemsMarque));
      $.each(itemsMarque, function(key, value) {
        //alert("k=" + key + " v=" + JSON.stringify(value));
        htmlOption += '<option value="' + value[0] + '" data-href="' + value[2] + '">' + value[1] + '</option>';
      });
    }
    $('#Year').empty();
    $('#Serie').html(htmlOption);
  });

  $('#go').click(function() {
    //alert('go_click');
    var selected = $('#Serie').find('option:selected');
    var href = selected.data('href');
    // alert('Go to: '+href);
    window.location = href;
  });
});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <select id="Marque">
            <option value="0">Choix du marque</option>
            <option value="bmw">bmw</option>
            <option value="mercedes">mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">audi</option>
            <option value="volswagen">volswagen</option>
        </select>
    <select id="Serie"></select>
    <select id="Year"></select>
    <input type="button" id="go" value="Go!" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```